# Mass file upload by user with metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online

Has anyone come across a solution for SharePoint online that will allow users to mass upload 50 files and at the same time tag with appropriate field and/or metadata?

The scenario I am trying to cater for is when my users upload 100 photographs that the are all tagged with the same metadata or field data depending on how I can get this to occur.

If I cannot find a way users are going to want to user folders and of course I don't want to allow that.

3rd party apps are an option but haven't found one to suite yet.

Anyone had a solution to this before?

Cheers,
Evan

Answer (score 0):

You should use document sets and share the columns that are going to be the same.